# Wrong output in predict function from R package 'recommenderlab'?

Tags: r, recommendation-engine, collaborative-filtering

I need to make a recommender based on a Yelp database, I've filtered the business reviews and the user and created a `realRatingMatrix` with user ratings for the respective businesses. Even though the matrix will be gigantic I'm just testing with a very small matrix first (`mdat` matrix).

```
#learning matrix
learningM <- as(mdat[1:8,],"realRatingMatrix")

# matrix to predict user recommendations
testM <- as(mdat[9:10,],"realRatingMatrix")

#using the learning matrix to create a UBCF recommender
rec <- Recommender(learningM, method = "UBCF")

#function that should output 2 business recommendations to users of testM
pre <- predict(rec, testM, n=2)
```

Instead I receive an output like this:

```
> as(pre,"list")
[[1]]
character(0)

[[2]]
character(0)
```

Why am I getting this output? Is the `predict` function calculating wrong results thus providing erroneous output or is my business column name a different text type so he can't output it correctly?

Edit: `mdat` matrix as requested, sorry for not putting it at the first place.

```
> dput(mdat)
structure(c(1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 4, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
3, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5), .Dim = c(10L, 10L), .Dimnames = list(
c("jqhP9mV2rYvmPdKvlOfp0g", "tqkkmL2NB19Sxeg1AaXnSA", "cNMJxBzmXA9N7krLvlrzlA", 
"9v3uIUTitC043Y4Qs54K1g", "nLUwyI34R-cAHLnmEGeLIg", "6SUSTwhfSFva9nbIDmoN7Q", 
"iCppbv3C7XvCyzIZnNQ7fg", "MUo7TLgR7sy1ob0MvxyPHQ", "GMVQyHMHNGplG3aof8jMcA", 
"VNGevHJuTxcou-Nhm8Q5RQ"), c("iZYDZvXoIT648EZOnEP0pQ", "HQJjHA6BRcRD0vR5askdkQ", 
"bul_5Ahk_QYLUAJ4Od27jg", "EOoj2h1Brzk1AhqScvIHDA", "roEQNfyPi3jRv3WFFr-f_g", 
"ffp58kYSK7dJGs5ER-5txw", "pvlM--HZY1a8SqMXiwEz1A", "mta3FuoNzjjGWQr9TCHGhA", 
"QeK3lOP-CTZS72YgeXiiqA", "57VozB9tq5SbNst9nO-jxA")))
```

Comment: The mistake is that no one can answer without the data. Post output from `dput(mdat)`

Comment: @BondedDust matrix added.

Comment: Most of the data is NA and there is no overlap in the dimnames of the training and test sets. So there is nothing in the training set that could be used to compute a similarly between the features of the training and test sets.

Comment: @BondedDust Humm ok. Can you explain better the "there is no overlap in the dimnames of the training and test sets"? You mean my test date doesn't have values in the same column as the ones in my training data? I just used a different method, instead of `UBCF` I used `POPULAR` and he at least gave me an output, so everything is correct I guess that just my training data is sparse and empty.

Comment: If the items rated by users 9 and 10 were not in the universe of items in the training set, how can there be any user-specific prediction? The "POPULARity" method might have some chance of delivering a rec simply by reporting the highest ratings beven by users 1-8, but it would not be using any results from the ratings offered by 9 and 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As explained by the vignette, recommenderlab](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/recommenderlab/vignettes/recommenderlab.pdf) is trying to solve a sparse matrix regression problem. But if the test set of recommendations from new users is not from the same space set of values as the training set, then there can be no construction of any sort of similarity measure for the new users with the old users. The algorithm needs to find some old-users who rated the same items as the new users before it can then deliver further items from the other old user ratings.

A simple populatity recommendation does not require finding any subset of raters who shared ratings with new users.